# Como ler variáveis de Múltiplos ambientes ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou tentando ler a partir do arquivo appsettings propriedades com diferentes valores, um pra cada ambiente.
Os meus arquivos são os seguintes, appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Stage.json no caso o sistema reconhece em quem ambiente esta trabalhando e acessa o arquivo correto, esta parte esta funcionando por que caso contrário o sistema no ambiente de stage não funcionária assim como no ambiente de produção para o cliente.
Ou seja este não é o problema, o meu problema é o seguinte estava desenvolvendo e funcionou perfeitamente no ambiente de Development, porém quando passei pra stage, não funcionou.

Eu tenho estes códigos atualmente:

appsettings.json:

```
"StringsConnection": {
    "canal": "plataforma-production",
    "link": "781115465H/1Tasdsdaaaa/K456546bb45654665fdg"
}

appsettings.Development.json:
"StringsConnection": {
    "canal": "plataforma-local",
    "link": "484ghj6ngfh/jg468fgh/dfg468df4g6864sdf84ds"
  },
```

appsettings.Stage.json:

```
"StringsConnection": {
    "canal": "plataforma-stage",
    "link": "dsf546/DSF86SD4F4DS/SAD6S8A4DSAdsf84dsa"
}
```

Estou acessando as propriedades "canal" e "link"

apiControlerQualquer.cs:

```
var canal= new collector_log
            {
                log = _config.GetValue<string>(
                   "ConnectionStrings:canal")
            };

var link= new collector_log
            {
                log = _config.GetValue<string>(
                "ConnectionStrings:link")
            };
```

na controller eu ainda tenho

```
  private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Methods_Utils(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _config = config;
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        //injeção de depencencias
        HelperController helper = new HelperController();

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {    
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{        
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();          
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
          {
              logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
              logging.AddConsole();
              logging.AddDebug();
              logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
          });              
}
```

A questão é, estou conseguindo acessar os valor no ambiente de Development porém, não estou conseguindo acessar os valores no ambiente de Stage, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Afinal está funcionando ou não!? Uma hora diz que sim, outra diz que não... Não dá para entender. O que vem a ser "Não estou conseguindo acessar os valores no ambiente de Stage"? Mesmo no ambiente te stage os valores são os de development, é isso?

Comment: Acho que não expliquei muito bem, eu consigo acessar no development, e não consigo na Stage. Em outras palavras no ambiente da Stage estou tendo problemas, não estou conseguindo acessar o valor!

Comment: E como está inicializando a aplicação? Qual o valor de ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT?

Comment: A aplicação esta incializando normalmente sem erro. No Visual Studio na aba Project no oção API Properties depois na aba Debug esta informando o seguinte: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  = Development

Comment: Caso não seja setado como variável de ambiente ou via linha de comando, o valor padrão é `Production`. Como o VS tem essa configuração, qndo corre a aplicação com o VS, é usado o ambiente `Development` e, por isso, é usado o `appsettings.Development.json`. Nos demais casos, será usado o `appsettings.Production.json`, caso exista. Não vejo como vc pretende usar o `appsettings.Stage.json`. Pelo menos não deixou claro na pergunta. Não é possível saber se é na sua máquina, para testes, ou em outra máquina. Nem se são feitas as devidas configs ou se foi alterado a forma de ler as configs na app.

Comment: A configuração do appsettings está funcionando, o servidor reconhece os devidos ambientes. Porém o que não estou conseguindo fazer é o seguinte: em ambiente de stage as variaveis que defini no appsettings.stage.json, não são reconhecidas, levando em consideração que está da mesma forma que no appsettings.development.json.

Comment: Funciona normalmente em ambiente de dev, porém quando faço o commit para a stage, ele não funciona mais, lembrando que o stage está no servidor AWS.

Comment: É como expliquei acima. Na sua máquina vai funcionar como `Development` por conta dessa configuração do VS. No stage, é necessário adicionar a variável de ambiente. Fazer isso vai depender de como está usando o AWS (se algum "as a service" deles ou máquina virtual) e qual o SO.

Comment: Já esta configurada a variável de ambiente e estou utilizando Kubernets e Docker com SO Linux.

Comment: Um ponto de atenção é que o linux é case sensitive. Verifique o nome do arquivo `appsettings.Stage.json` e o valor de `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` no seu container.

Comment: O nome do arquivo appsettings.Stage.json e o valor de ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT foi verificado e esta correto.

Comment: Já que essa parte está ok, então adiciona à sua pergunta o programa.cs e o startup.cs (as partes relevantes, caso haja), PF.

Comment: Pronto, adicionado os códigos de Program.cs e Startup.cs

Comment: Consegue fazer o download do teu container e confirmar que o arquivo `Stage` está presente? Outra opção seria fazer um teste removendo o `optional: true` do `AddJsonFile`, para verificar se a aplicação da erro ao iniciar.

Comment: `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)`

Comment: Pessoal muito Obrigado por tentarem me ajudar, eu finalmente resolvi o problema, estava ligado a outra parte do sistema, uma função de pegar ip não estava funcionando, ai dava erro ali, e o sistema parava ali, não prosseguia até a parte que desenvolvi, realmente pensei que fosse um problema nas variáveis de ambiente, até mesmo porque nem tinha mexido nessa função de pegar o ip, mas agora já resolvi. Muito obrigado a todos e em especial pro tvdias.